# Can't access event object as a result of 'lifting state up'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm going through react docs and I'm stuck on this:

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    console.log(event); // (*)
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}{this.renderSquare(1)}{this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}{this.renderSquare(4)}{this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}{this.renderSquare(7)}{this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ybbQJX

(*) I can't understand why event is accessible there. How does it manage to get transferred through all these methods. Furthermore, when i changed Square to this:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this); 
    }

    onClick(){
        this.props.onClick();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button className="square" onClick={this.onClick}>
                {this.props.value}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

I no longer had access to event (*). I got a mistake "Unexpected use of 'event'". And i have no idea why. Well, i'd guess that it's because arrow functions don't have their own `this`, but event doesn't seem to depend on that. They don't have `arguments` as well, but event is pretty much accessible without being specified in the parameters. And i also doubt that `super` has something to do with it either. I'd appreciate any clarification on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html
I think the problem might be that in the first case you console.log(event) directly in the event handler. In the second case your event handler is actually in the Square class so I’d be curious to see if you added a console.log(event) in the Square onClick method if it recognizes the event.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'directly in the event handler'? As i can see it, In the first case i'm logging event in the Board class. And you're absolutely right, I couldn't access event, even though I had added console.log(event) right into the Square class' onClick method. I mean, I know I can access the SyntheticEvent by adding a parameter, but what happens if I don't. And why arrow functions make the global event accessible in the other's class method, without explicitly passing it as an argument. Is it because some closure being created or something? Thanks for trying to help!